# Prolog: sort sublist in list

Tags: list, prolog, sublist

How to make it?
I need something like this:

```
?- elsort([d,s,a,[r,t,h]],X). 
X = [a, d, s, [h, r, t]].
```

But i get :

```
?- elsort([d,s,a,[r,t,h]],X).
X = [a, d, s, [r, t, h]].
```

My code:

```
elsort([],[]).
elsort([A|B],C):-
    elsort(B,D),
    elsortx(A,D,C).

elsortx(A,[X|B],[X|C]):-
    order(X,A),
    !,
    elsortx(A,B,C).
elsortx(A,B,[A|B]).

order(A,A2):-
    A @< A2.
```

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably make the sorting of sublists a two-phase operation. First, iterate over your source list, sorting each sublist found. When that's done, then actually sort the final list. The rationale is to avoid the repeated sorting of sublists.

Something like this:

```
my_sort( Unsorted , Sorted ) :-  % to sort a list of lists...
  sort_sublists( Unsorted, U ) , % - 1st pass: sort any sublists
  merge_sort( U , Sorted )       % - 2nd pass: actually sort the results
  .                              %

sort_sublists( [] , [] ) .          % an empty list has no sublists to sort
sort_sublists( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :- % otherwise...
  list(X) ,                         % - if the head is a list
  !,                                % - eliminate the choice point
  my_sort(X,Y)                      % - and sort the head (along with its sublists)
  .                                 %
sort_sublists( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ).   % otherwise (the head is not a list)

merge_sort( []       , [] ) .       % an empty list is sorted.
merge_sort( [A]      , [A] ) .      % list of 1 item is sorted.
merge_sort( [A,B|Cs] , Sorted ) :-  % otherwise, to sort a list of 2 or more items...
  partition([A,B|Cs] , L , R ) ,    % - partition it into two halves.
  merge_sort( L , L1 ) ,            % - then recursively sort the left half
  merge_sort( R , R1 ) ,            % - and recursively sort the right half
  merge( L1 , R1 , Sorted )         % - then merge the two now-order halves together
  .                                 % producing the final, sorted list

partition( []       , []     , []     ) .
partition( [L]      , [L]    , []     ) .
partition( [L,R|Xs] , [L|Ls] , [R|Rs] ) :- partition(Xs,Ls,Rs) .

merge( []     , []     , []  ) .
merge( [L]    , []     , [L] ) .
merge( []     , [R]    , [R] ) .
merge( [L|Ls] , [R|Rs] , [R,L|Xs] ) :-
  compare(CC,L,R) ,
  swap(CC,L,R,Lo,Hi),
  merge(Ls,Rs,Xs)
  .

swap( < , L , R , L , R ) .
swap( > , L , R , R , L ) .
swap( = , L , R , L , R ) .

list( X     ) :- var(X) , ! , fail .
list( []    ) .
list( [_|_] ) .
```

Note that `compare/3` is a built-in predicate that compares two terms in the standard order of things and returns an atom, one of `<`, `=` , `>`, with each having the obvious meaning. You could roll your own if you'd like:

```
compare(<,X,Y) :- X @< Y .
compare(>,X,Y) :- X @> Y .
compare(=,X,Y) :- X == Y .
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to sort the element itself if it is a list, e.g.:

```
elsort([A|B],C):-
  elsort(B,D),
  (is_list(A)->elsort(A, SA);SA=A),
  elsortx(SA,D,C).
```

Sample input:

```
 ?- elsort([d,s,a,[r,t,h]],X).
X = [a, d, s, [h, r, t]].
```